# How to list and re-arrange or manipulate Gutenberg Block Categories in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Anyone know how to re-arrange, manipulate the Block Categories in the Gutenberg Editor in Wordpress I can't even return a list of them as you can with the Blocks themselves, all I can find is 'getCategories' which doesn't seem do anything... the new documentation is not great at all.

Comment: I second this, all I can find is the get_block_categories() hook - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_block_categories/, but all it does is list the available blocks, can't seem to find a way to manipulate it at all.

Answer (score 9):

This did the trick for me to register a custom Guttenberg block and make it the first option in WP Admin editor:

```
function custom_block_category( $categories ) {
    $custom_block = array(
        'slug'  => 'my-blocks',
        'title' => __( 'My Test Blocks', 'my-blocks' ),
    );

    $categories_sorted = array();
    $categories_sorted[0] = $custom_block;

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $categories_sorted[] = $category;
    }

    return $categories_sorted;
}
add_filter( 'block_categories', 'custom_block_category', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter solution:

```
function custom_block_category( $categories ) {
    return array_merge(
        array(
            array(
                'slug' => 'my-blocks',
                'title' => __( 'My Test Blocks', 'my-blocks' ),
            ),
        ),
        $categories
    );
}
add_filter( 'block_categories', 'custom_block_category', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This removes any other category from the list.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks plain simple and should basically append the new category to the existing ones. I also just checked it. Prior to it, it's 6 categories and afterwards 7 categories. Also, it's basically the same approach as listed in the WordPress dev handbook (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#managing-block-categories), but just changing the order and thus inserting the own category at the front.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution is Good for PHP. But if someone wants to do that using JavaScript, there is also a good way.

```js
import { getCategories, setCategories } from '@wordpress/blocks';

const customBlockCategory = {
   slug: 'my-custom-block-category',
   title: __('My Custom Block Category', 'text-domain'),
   icon: 'wordpress', // or an SVG icon component as Element
}

// Then Just append the custom block category.
setCategories([
    ...getCategories(), // This is all default registered categories.
    customBlockCategory,
]);
```

If you want to add the category at first just append it first, like so -

```js
setCategories([
    customBlockCategory,
    ...getCategories(),
]);
```

Then this category blocks will be displayed first.

Hope, this will help many people.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is working when adding a new category

```
add_filter( 'block_categories_all' , function( $categories ) {

    // New category array
    $new_category = array(
        'slug'  => 'new-cat-slug',
        'title' => 'New cat title'
    );

    // Adding a new category to begging of categories array.
    array_unshift($categories , $new_category);

    return $categories;
} );
```